# Mapping Issue in elasticsearch 2.3.3

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose we have different mapping for the same field name in different record type in same index,Can we make same mapping over the the index for same field name?

> For eg,
>    we have index named **1000** and two record type as **school** and **college** .Both record type has field name  "location" with different mapping as given below.

For school :

```
"location":{
                "type":"multi_field",
                "fields":{
                    "location":{"type":"string","analyzer":"sortable"},
                    "contains":{
                        "type":"string",
                        "analyzer":"containsAnalyzer",
                        "search_analyzer":"standardAnalyzer"
                    }
                }
            }
For college:
"location":{
        "type":"string",
        "index":"not_analyzed"
      }
```

Is there any method to make similar mapping for **location** on both record type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with a good reason, check this very extensive explanation in the definitive guide.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping.html

In you case I would just add the raw variant as a multifield approach to location. That way you do have you not_analyzed variant.